# About concentration of eigenvalues values of a random symmetric matrix in a specific interval

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices, measure-concentration, random-functions, spectral-radius

Given a random symmetric matrix $M$ and two numbers $\lambda_\min$ and $\lambda_\max$ how do we calculate the expected or high probability value of the fraction of its eigenvalues which lie in the interval $[\lambda_{\min},\lambda_{\max}]$?

- I would like to know of references which might have achieved such an estimate for even any specific distribution of $M$
- In particular I am most curious about the case when $M$ is random PSD, $\lambda_\min =0$ and $\lambda_{\max} \lll  \Vert M \Vert_2$

Answer (score 3):

A random PSD matrix $M$ can be constructed by taking $M=WW^T$, with the $n\times n$ matrix elements of $W$ i.i.d. with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. For $n\gg 1$ the marginal distribution $\rho(\lambda)$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $W$ is given by the [Marcenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) 
$$\rho(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2 n}\sqrt{\frac{4n\sigma^2 }{\lambda}-1},\;\;0<\lambda<4n\sigma^2 ,$$
and then you can integrate from $0$ to $\lambda_{\rm max}<4n\sigma^2 $ to obtain the desired fraction $f$ of eigenvalues in the interval $(0,\lambda_{\rm max})$,
$$f=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_{\rm max} \left(4 n {\sigma}^2-\lambda_{\rm max}\right)}}{2 \pi  n {\sigma}^2}-\frac{2 \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{4 n {\sigma}^2}{\lambda_{\rm max}}-1}\right)}{\pi }+1.$$

For $\lambda_{\rm max}\ll 4n\sigma^2$ this has the asymptotics
$$f\rightarrow\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{\lambda_{\rm max}}.$$

[image]
<sub>$f$ versus $\lambda_{\rm max}/n\sigma^2$.</sub>

The $\sqrt\lambda_{\rm max}$ growth is generic for random PSD matrices. It arises because eigenvalue repulsion causes a $1/\sqrt\lambda$ accumulation of the eigenvalues near the hard spectral edge at $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Thanks! So this is a very specific distribution for which the computation seems to exist. Would you know of any general results of this kind?

Comment: it's not that specific: the matrix elements of $W$ can have any distribution, it does not need to be a Gaussian; the Marcenko-Pastur derivation does assume that the elements of $W$ are i.i.d., but the large-$n$ limit also holds if they are correlated, under similar conditions as the Wigner semicircle law for the GOE. Moreover, the $f\propto\sqrt{\lambda}_{\rm max}$ asymptotics is generic for a hard spectral edge at 0, so it should apply to any random PSD matrix.